# Proof of linear independence of coordinate basis vector

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vectors, mathematics

Given a chart $(O,\psi)$ on an $n$-dimensional differentiable manifold $M$, let $$X_\mu(f)=\frac{\partial f\cdot\psi^{-1}(x_1)}{\partial x_\mu}|_{\psi(p)},$$ where $p\in O$.

How do you prove that $\forall (O,\psi), \forall f\in \mathscr{F}_M$, the $n$ vectors in $\{X_\mu\}$ are linearly independent (for any $f$ and chart chosen)?

This was described as "easy to see" in Wald, and the following proof is supplied by a chinese textbook (微分几何入门与广义相对论). I believe this proof is bogus though, given that it assumes the special case of $f$ = the $\nu^{th}$ output of $\psi$ .

Said proof:

Let

1. $\Sigma a^\mu X_\mu=\vec{0}$.

Where $a\in R$

Consider $x^\nu(\nu=1,2,...,n)$, one may regard it function on the coordinate patch $O$. We apply both sides of equation (1.) to this function and should get the same thing.

By definition, $\vec{0}(x^\nu)=0$ for RHS.

LHS $=\Sigma a^\mu X_\mu(x^\nu)=\Sigma a^\mu\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x_\mu}|_{\psi(p)}=a^\nu$.

Therefore we have, for all $(\nu=1,2,...,n)$, $a^\nu=0$ from LHS = RHS, of course meaning all $a^\mu =0$.

QED

Is this proof valid? Why? if it is wrong as I suspected can anyone supply/point me to a correct proof?

Comment: Hopefully someone can correct me if I am wrong, but I think you are thinking of it the wrong way round. We require that if $\sum a^{\mu} X_{\mu} (f) = 0 \forall f$, then $a^{\mu} = 0$. We don't require that $\forall a^{\mu} \neq 0, \forall f,  \sum a^{\mu} X_{\mu} (f) \neq 0$. We have chosen a specific $f = x^{\nu}$ such that $\sum a^{\mu} X_{\mu} (x^{\nu}) = 0$ requires $a^{\nu} = 0$. But this doesn't mean that when $a^{\nu} \neq 0$, we require $\sum a^{\mu} X_{\mu} (f) = 0 \forall f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear independence simply means that $a^\mu X_\mu = 0$ implies $a^\mu=0$ for all $\mu\in\dim M$.
(Btw, I'm using the Einstein sum convention, i.e. $a^\mu X_\mu = \sum_{\mu = 1}^{\dim M}a^\mu X_\mu$)

The proof is quite correct. Let's restate it a bit.
The equation $a^\mu X_\mu = 0$ is true for all scalar functions $f$.
Thus it is also true for $x^\nu$ for every single $\nu\in \dim M$. Plugging this in gives

$$a^\mu X_\mu(x^\nu) = 0$$

on both sides.  By definition we have

$$a^\mu X_\mu(x^\nu) = a^\mu \left.\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^\mu}\right\vert_{\psi(p)} = a^\mu \delta_\mu^\nu = a^\nu = 0$$

So, for all $\nu \in \dim M$ follows $a^\nu=0$.
Therefore, $a^\mu X_\mu = 0$ indeed implies $a^\mu = 0$ for all $\mu \in \dim M$ and this is what we wanted to show.

Comment: ”$a^\mu X_\mu=0 $ is true for all scalar functions .“ This I can understand, but doesn't the requirement "let this $f=^\nu$" still restrict the result $a^\nu=0$ we find to be true only under this condition? In other words I cant help but feel that $a^\mu X_\mu (f)=0 \implies a^\nu=0$ （f is linearly independent）when $f=^\nu$. Don't we want to prove the general case so that we can use this theorem in the future? (e.g. in proving the vector transformation equation we have to use this theorem without having the specification $f=^\nu$)

Comment: @YG It's not simply a restriction. Picking $f=x^\nu$ is just the most simple way to extract $a^\nu=0$ from what we are given. I don't quite understand your doubts about why this result doesn't apply to all other scalar functions. Maybe you can clarify why this shouldn't be the case?
The argument really just is: this has to be true for all $f$ -> so especially for $x^\nu$.
And the $a^\mu$ do not depend on a scalar function $f$ anyway, so finding $a^\nu=0$ by making a choice of one certain $f$ is completely fine.

Comment: I understand now, thanks!